# How can I use functions and libraries from Node.js to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to use functions from Node.js to JavaScript but I don't know how to make the connection between them

I'm trying to use the next library in JavaScript

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

But the browser doesn't support "require"

Can any one helps me?

Comment: nodejs IS javascript ... did you mean you want to use nodejs libraries in a browser? besides that, you can't use nodejs ONLY libraries in a browser - browsers don't work like nodejs - usually for this example, mongoose ... you have a server that handles requests from the browser and does the database stuff

Comment: You can't use mongoose in the browser - what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -1):

You can't directly use Node.js packages inside a Javascript file without a node environment. But there is a cool way of using Node.js packages inside your Javascript file.

Visit [Skypack.dev](https://www.skypack.dev/) and use any npm package using the CDN.

For example, [mongoose](https://www.skypack.dev/view/mongoose) - https://www.skypack.dev/view/mongoose

Write your javascript code like this,

```html
<script type="module">
  import mongoose from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/mongoose';
</script>
```

> Note: Make sure you add `type="module"` attribute to your `<script>` tag.

Thank you!

Comment: Not that you can do anything useful with mongoose in the browser, even when loading it this way…

Comment: @deceze Totally agree with you, but one can use many other useful packages inside Javascript with Skypack